# Question about alternative interior angles

Tags: analytic-geometry, angle

The [source](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/alternate-interior-angles.html#:%7E:text=Alternate%20Interior%20Angles%20are%20a,c%20and%20f) given mentions that $c$ and $f$ are alternative interior angles.

Why $c$ and $d$ are not alternative interior angles? They should be  because they are both on the opposite sides of the transversal line and they are inside the two parallel lines.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

c and d are supplementary angles. They add up to give 180° and lie on the same line.